# Question about setting the key of NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a class named A;

In A.h

```
@interface A : NSObject {

    NSString *str;
    NSNumber *num;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *str;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber *num;
```

A is superclass of B.

In B.h

```
@interface B : A {

    NSString *BStr;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *BStr;

@end
```

Now I need set object of B as a key of a NSDictionary.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    B *key = [[B alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"object" forKey:key];
}
```

Then class B should implement NSCopying protocal.

I wanted to know if this code is correct? Should I do something about property of class A?

In B.m

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    B *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    copy.BStr = [[self.BStr copyWithZone:zone] autorelease];
    return copy;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy str and num in copyWithZone too:

```
copy.str = [[self.str copyWithZone:zone] autorelease];
copy.num = [[self.num copyWithZone:zone] autorelease];
```